# OutOfMemory exception when trying to download multiple files as a Zip file using Ionic.Zip dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memorystream

This is my working code that I used to download multiple files as a zip file using `Ionic.Zip` dll. File contents is stored in a SQL database. This program works if I try to download 1-2 files at a time, but throws an `OutOfMemory` exception if I try to download multiple files as some of the files may very large.

Exception occurs when it's trying to write in to `outputStream`.

How can I improve this code to download multiple files or is there a better way to download multiple files one by one rather than zipping them to a one large file?

Code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadMultipleFiles()
{
    string connectionString = "MY DB CONNECTIOBN STRING";

    List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();
    var query = "MY LIST OF FILES - FILE METADA DATA LIKE FILEID, FILENAME";
    documents = query.Query<Document>(connectionString1).ToList();

    List<Document> DOCS = documents.GetRange(0, 50); // 50 FILES

    Response.Clear();     
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        foreach (var doc in DOCS)
        {
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] content = GetFileContent(doc.FileContentId); // This method returns file content
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);

            zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary // edited

            zip.AddEntry(doc.FileName, content);
        }

        zip.Save(outputStream);
    }

    return File(outputStream, "application/zip", "allFiles.zip");
}
```

Comment: @ Yuval Itzchakov  I have listed my code in order to provide the context. But my question is how to download multiple files one by one without facing above mentioned error ?

Comment: If you need a large amount of files in-memory at once, you might consider running your process as x64 instead of x86.

Comment: `AddEntry(doc.FileName, content);` is wrong, post exact working code.

Comment: Put the `stream` in a `using` block, just like the `ZipFile`.

Comment: @KeithPayne - a good practice but because the MemoryStream.Dispose() does nothing this is certain not to be the solution.

Comment: zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary; solved my problem.  Can some one explain me why my queston has been marked down ?

Answer (score 1):

Download the files to disc instead of to memory, then use Ionic to zip them from disc. This means you don't need to have all the files in memory at once.